# How to aggregate a newly created document in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem when using `.create()` to create new document, I need to `$lookup`  aggregate 1 field in the document. The problem I am facing is .aggregate is not working on the returned document after created and I get an error if I try to do that: `.aggregate is not a function`. How can I do correctly aggregate a new created document ?

My code:

```
let newsDoc = await newsModel.create({...});
newsDoc = await newsDoc.aggregate([...]); // not working
res.status(200).send(newsDoc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.aggregate()` method is a function inside the mongoose model instance, which is essentially a wrapper around the official MongoDB driver.

`.create()` returns the object that it has been created and **not** the model instance.

See this:

```
// Here newsDoc is the news document inserted and NOT the news Model 
let newsDoc = await newsModel.create({...});

// Hence this
// newsDoc = await newsDoc.aggregate([...]);
// Causes error

// For you to aggregate, use the model reference: 
// This would work
newsDoc = await newsModel.aggregate([...]); // not working
```

You can pass the _id that is returned from the `create()` method inside the `aggregate()` to filter out the object that is running currently in the context.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, you are my benefactor!